# Push notification Flutter with Yes/No functionality

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am new to flutter and trying to implement push notification.

1. Connect app with firebase - Done
2. Implement push notification - [Done](https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging)
3. Need to implement notification with Yes/No action
   Yes -> Accept the request of the notification
   No  -> Reject
4. Should be able to take onTap gesture from locked phone.

Thank you for your help :)

Edit: How can I implement WhatsApp like reply notification using Flutter? Here, I need 'Yes' text to accept the request even if app is terminated (accessibility of app when terminated is already handled). I require help on adding Button below the notification.

[Push Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJixc.png)
Here the notification displays the app name, title and body. I would like to add Yes or No with color Green and Red respectively below the body.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with native side and implement notification as you want and deal with flutter using flutter method channel.